# How to create login implementation using CQS pattern?

Tags: authentication, cqrs

In the CQS pattern, the queries are responsible only for reading the database and not modifying the state. To create, update or delete objects in the database we use commands.
If I want to try login the user I need to send login and password to the server side. If the credentials are ok as a response I expect to get some userDto object. In a case when the client typed proper login but the wrong password I need to modify the state of the user object and increase the amount of failed login attempts.

In theory, the best option would be to send only one request to the database e.g. GetUserDataQuery
But if the query would modify the state of the user entity it means that we break the CQS separation rule.

The other option I see is to send a command first, called e.g. TryToLoginCommand and if the HTTP response is 200 then I can send a GetUserDataQuery. In such a case, we send 2 requests instead of one. But is this way 100% secure?

Maybe there is some other solution which I can not see?
And no in my case I can't use 3rd party service like Azure or Amazon for authentication and authorization. 
Which way is the proper one, most secure and prevent brute force attacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commands don’t have to be generated in response to user input.  You submit the username/pw for validation on the server (I hope you’re not sending the users pw back to the front end for validation).  The controller for that request issues the query necessary to validate the user.  If the user is valid then the controller creates and executes the command to update what is necessary, then returns a success message to the UI.  If login fails, again you execute a command to update what’s necessary, and return the num failed logins.  It’s only one request from the UI, but runs a query and command on the server side.

Comment: From a technical point of view what would be the proper name for such a request, because it's not a command or query, hmm?

Comment: What comes from the user is a request.  The controller interprets the request and creates any queries or commands necessary to fulfill the request.